# Save ImageButton State in Adapter Class

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, sharedpreferences

**Background:**

Hi, I am working on an e-commerce food app. For a section of the app, I wanted to create a favorites list where users can favorite their choice of food in the list view and the Favorited food will be added to a favorite list. Right now, I am able to change the image button state by setting image resource in my product list adapter class. However, i cannot maintain the state after the session is closed or reopened. I reckon it needed some data saving mechanism such as saved preferences? So my question is:

**How to save image button state in an adapter class**

Below are part of my codes and by the way I am using sqlite to store my food aka products

**ListProductListAdapter Class:**

```
public class ListProductListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private int layout;
private ArrayList<Product> productList2;

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return productList2.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return productList2.get(position);
}

public ListProductListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Product> productList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.productList2 = productList;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder2 {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textName, textStall, textPrice;
    Button addCartButton;
    ImageButton favBtn;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View row = view;
    ListProductListAdapter.ViewHolder2 holder = new ListProductListAdapter.ViewHolder2();

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.listFoodImage);
        holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listProductName);
        holder.textStall = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listProductStall);
        holder.textPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listProductPrice);
        holder.addCartButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.addToCartButton);
        holder.favBtn = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.favouriteButton);


        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ListProductListAdapter.ViewHolder2) row.getTag();
    }

    Product product = productList2.get(position);

    holder.textName.setText(product.getProductName());
    holder.textStall.setText(product.getProductStall());
    holder.textPrice.setText(product.getProductPrice());

    byte[] productImage = product.getProductImage();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(productImage, 0, productImage.length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    // favorite button
    holder.favBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View favBtn) {
            favBtn.setSelected(!favBtn.isSelected());
            if(favBtn.isSelected()){
                ((ImageButton)favBtn).setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Added to Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                ((ImageButton)favBtn).setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Removed from Favorites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });

    // cart button
    holder.addCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, AdministratorActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    holder.favBtn.setTag(productList2.get(position));
    return row;

}
```

**ListActivity class:** (With standard android drawer activity)

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

GridView gridView;
ArrayList<Product>list;
ListProductListAdapter adapter = null;
 @Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ListProductListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_product_item, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


    //get data from sqlite
    Cursor cursor = LoginActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("select * from product");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(1);
        String name = cursor.getString(2);
        String stall = cursor.getString(3);
        String price = cursor.getString(4);
        list.add(new Product(image,id,name,stall,"S$ "+price));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_favourites) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_trackOrder) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logOut) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

I spent hours researching and to no avail could not find a solution for my situation. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: use sqlite database

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences to save the state permanently instead of using database.

Comment: are you using sqlite database to store product ?

Comment: @Shruti sharedpref is used for small size of data. sqlite is best option

Comment: @Divyesh True! But he just wants to save the button state and thats not a big data.

Comment: but favorite list size increase then it is hard to maintain button state for all items

Comment: In that case database is best.

Answer (score 1):

As you are retrieving your datas from a sqlite database, the best solution to me seems to add a column on your model that would store the isFavorite.
If the user marks the food as favorites, then update your food raw by setting isFavorite to true.
Then in your adapter, read this field and update image accordingly.

So when user will click your button, just set in your sqlite database the isFavorite to true for the concerned object.

Then in your adapter you will have a condition like this one :

```
if(product.isFavorite()) {
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(favoriteImage);
} else {
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(notFavImage);
}
```